# Modifying the "Spaces" plist on OSX to set default desktops

Tags: macos, osx-lion, plist, osx-snow-leopard

I am currently attempting to default an application to all desktops by modifying the plist associated with "Spaces" on 10.6 (and 10.7). On Snow Leopard, it's possible to set the default desktop for an application by going to System Preferences > Expose and Spaces, and setting the application to appear on all spaces by default. This works as expected, and my application appears on all desktops.

However, I am looking for a pragmatic approach, and would like to be able to set this feature from within my application. I found the plist files associated with each OS:

```
OS X 10.7: ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist
```

and

```
OS X 10.6: ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
```

Editing these files (in reference to application desktop defaults), then restarting the dock with *killall Dock* does not affect where my application shows up in Spaces.

I've also tried using *defaults* to set my default desktop with:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-app-bindings -dict-add com.mybundle.thing  65544
```

This also failed to work, in that the application did not associate with the correct desktops (or all desktops, as the above command shows).

Both of these methods make the application show up in the System Preferences panel, along with the correct Space assignment. However, it just fails to work unless I assign it directly from the System Preferences.

Is there something else that I need to set, along with the plist, to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.7 appears to store "all spaces" as the string `AllSpaces`.

For reference, it binds apps to the main desktop with an empty string, and to other spaces based on the space's `uuid` value.

Comment: Has anyone had luck doing this programmatically in 10.8, and having the system actually honor your changes without you having to change and re-set the preference by way of clicking on the dock icon?

Answer (score 1):

This Applescript worked for me in OSX 10.8.5 for a similar project, 
but it only lists the names of each Space, (I had 9 Spaces.) It's a simple way to access the plist data. I'm sure it could be tweaked to rewrite the plist.

```
tell application "Finder" to set propsLST to alias ((home as text) & ¬
"Library:Preferences:com.apple.spaces.plist") as text

tell application "System Events" to set theSPACES to value of every property list item of property list item "Space Properties" of property list item ¬
 "SpacesConfiguration" of contents of property list file propsLST

set spacesLST to {}

repeat with eachSPACE in every item of theSPACES
  set {spaceNAM, spaceWNDW} to eachSPACE as list
  set end of spacesLST to spaceNAM
end repeat

return spacesLST
```